# Using CLI to start using SageMaker in browser

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In the case of using AWS only via aws cli, how can I open a sagemaker app in the browser if I already create sagemaker app and have apparn?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CreatePresignedDomainUrl API ([create-presigned-domain-url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-domain-url.html) CLI command) with domain id and user profile name to get a presigned url that will allow you to open the SageMaker Studio app.